# No WiFi, Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit, notebook Asus X75VD

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

Can't make wifi to work on Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit, notebook Asus X75VD:

```
*-network DISABLED 
description: Wireless interface
product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: wlan0
version: 01
serial: 20:168:09f:32
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.8.0-19-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
resources: irq:17 ioport000(size=256) memory:f7900000-f7903fff

dan@asus:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
[sudo] password for dan: 
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

Any help?

Comment: The question linked to as a duplicate is not at all a duplicate, and doesn't provide an answer. I added a comment there to help anyone who comes here looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `rfkill` blocked your wifi.

Run this in Terminal:

`sudo rfkill unblock wifi`

With `rfkill list` you can check if your wifi is unblocked. After that you should be fine.

For more info regarding `rfkill` follow this link:

[RF-Kill](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/RFKill.html)